# How do I export a single activity with all dependent resources from one project to another project?

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, resources, drawable

I have a Android application project with an Activity I want to export. Unfortunately, it's all resources (drawables, layouts, strings, styles) are merged with other project's resources.

How do I take-out the Activity I need with all dependant resources into another project?

Comment: Two questions- does the Activity know all the resources it is using? And do you want to remove the resources and activity or only copy them?

Comment: Currently I want to take one single activity from a project to my other project.

Comment: So remove the Activity from Project A along with all its resources, none of which are required in Project A, then add them to Project B?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do this manually. There is no option in Eclipse -- or any other Android-aware IDE, AFAIK -- to "export" an activity and its resources. In Eclipse, an activity and its resources are simply a basket of files; Eclipse does not know that they have an particular relationship.